# How would I define a many-to-many relationship between 3+ models in Django?

Tags: python, django

Right now I have these models: Movie, MovieFormat (eg, dvd, bluray, etc), Region, and I'd like to make a relationship between these to store (Movie, MovieFormat, Region, Date) tuples (movie releases)

I could just put a many-to-many field on Movie referencing Region through another model that has format and date fields, but that doesn't seem like the 'right' way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand completely what you are trying to do, but i think you are seeing this in the wrong way.

With the ideas i have in mind about what is a Movie (i'm trying to think object oriented here), what you should use is something like this:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    format = models.ForeignKey(MovieFormat)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    date = models.Datefield()
    ... other fields you want, like title for instance
```

With a model like this, you can store in your database (stop thinking in objects now) movies with different formats (formats are stored in other table so you have your database normalized), different region and dates for each movie (same thing with region as with format here).

Is this what you want? If no, try to be more specific with your question... Add an example with some movies and their relations with regions and formats...

**EDIT :**

Now i see what you want. I don't know exactly how to name the model i'm going to add, but i'm sure you are going to find an appropiate name:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    ... fields that you want for a movie, like foreing key to a producer for instance

class MovieEdition(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    format = models.ForeignKey(MovieFormat)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    date = models.Datefield()
    ... other fields, like movie title for that region (the related region)
```

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: I don't want format/region/date to be fields of the movie model itself, because the same movie can, for example, come out on DVD in europe on one day, and in North America a few months later, or it could come out on DVD first, then on Blu-Ray, etc etc

Comment: that makes sense. I was overthinking it.